# Terraform: How to set guestOS in terraform vsphere VM

Tags: vmware-vsphere, terraform

I try to create some VMs with terraform, with different guest OS.
But all are created as "Other Linux (64-bit)".
AS soon as the vm's are created they pxe boot -> this works fine.

**this is my instance.tf**

```
custom_configuration_parameters {
  "guestOS" = "centos64Guest"
}
```

**This is print out after apply:**

```
 vsphere_virtual_machine.test2: Creating...
  custom_configuration_parameters.%:       "" => "1"
  custom_configuration_parameters.guestOS: "" => "centos64Guest"
```

**This is actual VM:**

```
Guest OS
Other Linux (64-bit)
(VM version 11)
```

Really grateful for some guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're using the correct parameter for the Guest OS type. According to terraform's documentation, the parameter is guest_id, and if it's not set, it defaults to other-64, which seems to match your experience.

Source: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/vsphere/r/virtual_machine.html#guest_id